# Javascript/JQuery event for Chrome blocking insecure content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

If a page is served over https but the associated files are served from a non-secure http website, Chrome will throw the “insecure content” warning. Is there an event/property that I could be using to know when Chrome has blocked an unsecure content and also know if the user allowed the insecure content. A shield appears at the right of the adress bar when Chrome loads "insecure content" and the user has the possibility to click on this shield and still run the script. Is there any event for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this would be to serve a file over non-https, that would include a function to run if they allow non-secure content.

This script will obviously only be included if they've allowed the non-secure content to be loaded, and therefore works as your event check. You can therefore also check if these *haven't* been allowed by storing a global variable in the non-secure file & checking for it in a secure JS file (or within the document).

Obviously, if you're serving content via SSL, you should really ensure all of your content included is also over SSL.

Comment: -1 You just tested whether an environment was secure by making it unsecure